# discord.py Bot not always deleting messages

Tags: python, python-3.6, discord.py

As a little test, I'm making a bot for discord that will take a message I send, delete it, and have the bot send the message. I've got some stuff working, but I have a couple of problems.

First, the bot won't always delete messages.

With this code

```
if message.content.startswith("H"):
    print("test")
    print(message.author)
    msg=message.content
    await client.delete_message(message)
    await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
```

the bot will only sometimes delete my message. Any idea why?

Second, I want it to only repeat my messages, but when I do this;

```
if message.author=="Myusername#1234":
    print("test")
    print(message.author)
    msg=message.content
    await client.delete_message(message)
    await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
```

Nothing happens. No error, just nothing. Can anyone help?

P.S: `Myusername#1234` is just an example, and not what I'm putting in.

Comment: Note that the ` in the second bunch of code isn't actually there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first code example, your bots' message will also go through the `if` statement and will just be stuck in a loop of writing messages that start with "H" and deleting them.

You should update it to something like

```
  if message.content.startswith("H") and message.author.id != "bot_id":
```

As for the second code example, your best bet is to use user IDs since they don't change

```
if message.author.id == "user_id":
```

If you really want to use something else you can do `message.author.name` or `message.author.nick`

Comment: For the first one, I do have it so it won't reply to itself, but it still does that. As for the second one, thanks! I didn't know you could get user IDs

Comment: I think the problem you're experiencing is that the bot deletes the message but your discord client doesn't show it as deleted. I've had this happen sometimes, but nobody but you sees the message so it's effectively deleted anyway. Hope this helped!

Comment: It did help! And both of your suggestions helped! Thank you!